# GitHub : commit display previous account username

Tags: git, github

I have one issue with github , before month i have setup git account (user1) on github and worked with git from my system. now i have created second account (user2) and add new rsa_id key in ~/.ssh folder (take backup of old keys in another folder).

Now when i follow the steps shown on github

> Global setup:
>
> Set up git   git config --global user.name "user2"
>    git config
>   --global user.email user2@gmail.com
>
> Next steps:
>
> mkdir Web
>    cd Web
>    git init
>    touch README
>   git add README
>    git commit -m 'first commit'
>    git remote
>   add origin git@github.com:user2/Web.git
>    git push -u origin
>   master

when i committed it would display previous account username (user1). what should be issue here and how can i resolve this?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

It should print out the `user2` username that you want. If not, make sure you have added the keys properly to the account and the proper keys are being presented. Use `-v` flag in the above command to see what's happening.

Note that Github uses the configured email to associate commits with the user. So verify that it is really set ( `git config -l` etc. and verify)